# linux - setting order in which files are read or output with utilities (sorting)

Tags: shell, files, zsh, wildcards, sort

I'm having issues with programs reading files in the wrong order, and also outputting in an undesirable order with utilities such as `ls`.

I've tried some of the `LC_COLLATE` options, but none of them fit the preference I seek, so I figured there must be something more I can do.

Examples of commands producing wrong order:

```
user@host: /home/user/Video $ mpv *.mkv
```

There are 150 files in /home/user/Video, and here are the first 12 a command from a program like `mpv *.mkv` would read:

```
TVSeriesName - 01.mkv
TVSeriesName - 02.mkv
TVSeriesName - 03.mkv
TVSeriesName - 04.mkv
TVSeriesName - 05.mkv
TVSeriesName - 06.mkv
TVSeriesName - 07.mkv
TVSeriesName - 08.mkv
TVSeriesName - 09.mkv
TVSeriesName - 10.mkv
TVSeriesName - 100.mkv
TVSeriesName - 101.mkv
```

It's reading 100 before it reads 11, even with leading zero.

Ideally, it should read them in the correct 1-150 order even without a leading zero.

What I want is to have a universal order in which files are read and sorted that resembles the default of the `ranger` file manager.

Example:

```
.1-hiddendir/
.2-hiddendir/
.a-hiddendir/
.b-hiddendir/
.C-hiddendir/
.d-hiddendir/
.E-hiddendir/
1-dir/
2-dir/
A-dir/
b-dir/
c-dir/
D-dir/
.1-dotfile
.2-dotfile
.a-dotfile
.b-dotfile
.C-dotfile
1-file
2-file
a-file
B-file
c-file
```

**OS:** Arch Linux, **FS:** ext4

What can I do with environment settings, or anything, in a Linux distribution to achieve this?

Comment: Surely you want two leading zeroes?

Comment: you need to rename your files so that they ALL have the SAME number of digits in the numeric portion of the filename, left-padded with zeroes.  e.g. if you have more than 99 files, you'll need three digits: `001`, `011`, `100`, etc.  if more than 999, then 4 digits: `0001`, `0011`, `0100`, etc.

Comment: I don't want two leading zeroes. I'm looking for consistency, and I'm asking this question because I believe there must be some way for the shell or filesystem to determine order other than by having matching number of digits for all files in a directory.

Comment: I don't see why it seemed surprising that one didn't work, is all. I don't *think* the locale can have that sort of collation behaviour, but I would be interested to find out.

Comment: `zsh` with `numeric_glob_sort` enabled will treat numeric substrings as numbers for sorting filename generation, which helps part of your problem. I don't know of one that sorts directories first, although in zsh again you could use `*(/) *(^/)` with `glob_dots` to get some of the way there. None of that helps with `ls`.

Comment: I completely forgot to mention I use zsh, and I added numericglobsort and globdots to my list of existing setopt, and that did the trick for the order in which files are read by programs. I'd still like to find a general cure for most utilities which probably involves LC_COLLATE

Comment: "The order in which files are read by programs" is the order you told them to, not anything to do with the program reading them. I suspect you'd have to write your own locale to get general sorting to behave that way, and I'm not sure it's even possible to do it then. A more focused question on that topic might be more likely to be seen by someone who knows about doing that.

Comment: (1) I don’t know of any way to get `100` to sort before `11`, and I would be interested in learning about one, if it exists.  You understand what’s happening, right?  `100` sorts before `11` the same way “ALL” sorts before “AM”.  (2) Some versions of `ls` support a `--group-directories-first` option.  If it works on your system, try `alias ls='ls --group-directories-first'` (or whatever works in your shell).  (3a) If you have additional information to clarify your question, please [edit] it into the question instead of posting it in comments.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3b) [zsh] and [wildcards] would probably be more useful as tags than [environment-variables], [files], and [filesystems].  (While it’s good to provide all relevant information, the filesystem type probably isn’t relevant to this question.)   (4) You say (in your last comment) “…that did the trick for the order in which files are read by programs.  I'd still like to find a general cure for most utilities …”.  That doesn’t make much sense to me.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Programs that take filename arguments generally read files in the order that the filenames are presented; for example, `cat in the hat` reads the files `in`, `the`, and `hat` in that order.  If you’re talking about commands like `mpv *.mkv`, you should clarify that you’re talking about the order in which the shell does filename expansion; i.e., expands wildcards (globs).  And I don’t understand what you mean by “utilities” if it’s different from “programs”.  You would improve the quality of your question if you would use standard terminology,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  or, failing that, explain what you mean.  (5) If you’re talking about the order of filename expansion versus the order of the output from `ls`, I’m sorry to say that I doubt that there will be any unified solution.

Comment: @nixon, believing something doesn't make it so.  lots of people believe things that aren't true, or that are obviously absurd and ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -name '*.mkv' -print0 | sort -Vz | xargs -0r mpv
```

This uses `find` to output a NUL-separated of list all filenames matching '*.mkv' in the current directory, then GNU `sort` (with `-z` or `--zero-terminated` for NUL-separated input and `-V` or `--version-sort` to sort the filenames), and finally, `xargs -0r mpv` to run `mpv` with all the filenames in sorted order as the arguments.

This will work with any filename, even those with spaces, line-feeds, or shell meta-characters in the name.

AFAIK, only GNU `sort` and FreeBSD's `sort` currently support the `-z` or `--zero-terminated` option.